# Alphanumeric text returns as NA

Tags: r

I am pulling a file from excel into R and all seems to work reasonably well except for one of my columns that contains alphanumeric character eg 12345Name,when I pull this in I get NA for all these cells.

I done a little test and removed the letters for example 12345 this seems to pull in fine. what am I doing wrong.

what has also thrown me off is I have a column with postcode for example sw165NL and this seems to pull in fine without issues, any ideas

Comment: This may be caused because the first cells of that column have only numbers. When R reads the file, it "guesses" the type of each column by reading the type of the first `n` cells of each one of them. It your column had numeric cells on the first `n` ones, R considers the whole column to be numeric. When it finds alphanumeric, then it tries to convert to numeric, hence the `NA`

Comment: Try to read in all data as character/text. Do the conversion to the desired formats after importing.